# Jquery file upload / BlueImp - Can't get size on Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, file, internet-explorer, upload

I'm having a problem getting the size of a file on internet explorer. I am using Jquery file upload, and this is the piece of code that is not working:

```
$("#link").click(function () {
        $("#multiple").click();
    });

    $(function () {
        'use strict';
        // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
        $('#multiple').fileupload({
            add: function (e, data) {
                var fileAux = data.files[0]
                var size = fileAux.size; //size property does not exists on ie
```

It's working on chrome and Firefox but not on IE. I already tested other tutorials on IE and there are no problems in getting the file size.
I used page inspector and the fileaux var only has the name property...

Any help?

Comment: I believe this only works in browsers which support the File API. Which IE version are you using?

Comment: I'm using IE 11. I already tested the blueimp widget on other website and the data.files[0] has the size property. But on my solution I only get the name property.